# english novels like “the worst witch” for boys

Tags: pre-schooler, primary-schooler

I'm looking for a wizard book for my kid, hopefully similar level as "The Worst Witch", i.e. easier than the Harry Potter series, but for boys.

Hopefully it is suitable for boys around 5-7 years old, has interesting stories so that my kid will enjoy it meanwhile enrich the vocabularies, though happening in a wizard's world but actually looks like the real world with school life, and not too dark (e.g. death is a big topic and killing i take it too much for a 5-7 years old).

Any recommendation pls?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't do recommendation questions here.  You might have better luck on a more traditional style forum.

Comment: What are books for boys?

Comment: @justathought i can't define it, but boys and girls are different right, for example, girls likes pink more .. although peppa pig is an exception.

Comment: @athos Boys and girls have different genitalia. It has been societally imposed upon children to be different, like different colors, or prefer different media. http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20141117-the-pink-vs-blue-gender-myth

Comment: @justathought to be politically correct, there's nothing boys (or men) can do that girls (women) cannot. but, they are different.

Comment: Psychologically? Physically? How? I'm suggesting that it may not be in the best interest of your child to put them into the "boy box" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxic_masculinity). For all you know, your child could grow up to be anywhere on the gender spectrum. I think we're getting off topic here though. This discourse has led me to an answer I believe might suffice: go with your child to the library or book store and have *them* pick the book that *they* want to read. I was reading way above my age level precisely because my parents did this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend "The Worst Witch". It is easier than the Harry Potter series and does not (despite the wizarding nature of the book) have any spells cast on it rendering the text invisible to boys.

I would also recommend giving serious thought to designating literature as 'for boys' or 'for girls', especially at such a young age. Illiteracy is enough of an issue these days without adults placing certain books 'off limits' for such silly reasons.

Comment: can we have a +10 button please